# htaccess - how to handle different directory name on server and on local machine?

Tags: .htaccess

my website is stored on server in directory /

on my development machine is stored in directory /mysite

problem is that all links are related to root directory name (ie. /images/contact.html), and they can not be valid on my local server.

can you tell me which .htaccess directive is required, to make enable links on my local server?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /mysite
```

which would make it the root if I understood it correctly.

But i am not sure if that is only after the rules or as a global change.

Otherwise you could try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) mysite/$1 [L]
```

Comment: tnx! but what about css files that are included in html source? is it possible to rewrite all kind of links (images, css, js) with this rule?

Comment: not sure about css files but i guess it would, try it :) it won't hurt.

Comment: i tried of course, that's why i'm askin :)

Comment: if you had tried you would know the answer, unhappyly like i said i am not sure (since i never used it for that porpouse but in theory it should work) and currently i don't have any place to test it for you to tell you.